How to manage custom class options with xkeyval?
Greetings!
First of all, I apologise if this question is somewhat duplicated. I have conducted research within this community, but the threads I found do not fully address my specific needs (or at least I believe so).
My question concerns the usage of the xkeyval package, specifically: how can I manage options passed to my custom class?
For instance, let's say I have a custom class named myclass. How can I use xkeyval to check the options passed and proceed accordingly? For example, I want to allow the user to specify a language option that accepts two values: en for English and pt for Portuguese. More languages may be added in the future, so a boolean-based solution is not suitable.
Additionally, I want the class to:

Check whether the user provided a language option in the document class: \documentclass[language=en]{myclass}.
If no option is specified, default to English (en).

Here is what I've tried so far:
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\define@choicekey*{myclass}{language}[en]{en,pt}{%
    \def\myclass@language{#1}%
    \ifx#1en\relax
        \RequirePackage[english]{babel}%
    \else
        \ifx#1pt
            \RequirePackage[portuguese]{babel}%
        \else
            \PackageWarning{myclass}{Invalid language '#1'. Defaulting to English.}%
            \RequirePackage[english]{babel}%
        \fi
    \fi
}{%
    \PackageWarning{myclass}{Language not specified. Defaulting to English.}%
    \RequirePackage[english]{babel}%
}

\DeclareOptionX{language}{%
  \setkeys{myclass}{language=#1}%
}

\ProcessOptionsX*

I’ve already delved into the xkeyval documentation, but to be honest, I’m a bit confused by the concepts of \define@choicekey and \setkeys.
I’m relatively new to this concept, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I wouldn't use xkeyval but the inbuilt keyval support from LaTeX.

Can you give me some pointers in why keyval can be better than xkeyval?

@UlrikeFischer Isn't referring to keyval but to l3keys which is built into the latex kernel. For basic use see clsguide and for the full set of possibilities see interface3.

Excellent! I’ll definitely delve into that. However, if you’d like to contribute with a MWE, I’d be really grateful. Just a quick edit to say that the clsguide document that you provided is exceptionally amazing and is going to be a great help in my work. Thank you once again!

you should also look at usrguide, if you're not aware of it. aside from the advice to use l3keys, I would not do this at all. it is far better for users to do \documentclass[british]{<classname>} than to try to handle this yourself. for example, you are making it unnecessarily difficult for users to include properly marked up quotations in other languages or to get proper hyphenation in bib entries. you are also making it almost impossible to use british hyphenation rather than american, for example. if the class is for purely personal use, that's one thing. but don't impose this.

why would you restrict the class to just en and pt rather than allow all babel languages?

apart from using the bult in latex option processing rather than xkeyval  do not do \ifx#1en\relax  that is false for en but true for aa in which case it would return en\relax (and generate an error as typesetting en is not allowed at that point,)  \ifx tests the first two tokens, so the first two letters of #1 it is not testing #1 against en.

Thank you for the recommendations, @cfr. I really appreciate it! Perhaps I chose a poor example of the options I want to use. What you mentioned about the language options is very true; however, let's say I want the user to choose a school or even a color for cover customisation. Perhaps that could be a viable option. My custom class is already working with passing these options, but I just wanted to assign some keys for a better user experience from my perspective.

@DavidCarlisle, please refer to the comment I posted above. Also, let me thank you for the pointers you provided regarding my mistake - I truly appreciate your guidance!

I'll link to an post that has a small complete example of a class defining some key=value keys

I do believe it is indeed a duplicate question, and therefore the answer remains the same. Thank you @DavidCarlisle again for the time you’ve spent and, once again, for the guidance you’ve provided.
